# SSRS Switch statements for multiple conditions

Tags: if-statement, reporting-services, switch-statement

I'm attempting to use a SWITCH statement in order for Report Builder to tell me the premium depending on the level of cover that's selected for this particular part of a policy.

The statement I'm using:

```
=SWITCH(Fields!Salon_Stock_Equipment_Cover.Value="NOTREQ", "Not Required", 
Fields!Salon_Stock_Equipment_Cover.Value="1500", "22.40", 
Fields!Salon_Stock_Equipment_Cover.Value="2500", "33.60", 
Fields!Salon_Stock_Equipment_Cover.Value="5000", "39.20")
```

I'm using this in Report Builder.

I'm expecting the string to return either "Not Required", "22.40", "33.60" or "39.20" depending on the values that are pulled through. When I run it at the moment, it just returns blank.

How can I achieve what I want?

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? What is currently happening?

Comment: I'm expecting the string to return either "Not Required", "22.40", "33.60" or "39.20" depending on the values that are pulled through. 

When I run it at the moment, it just returns blank.

Comment: The entire report returns blank or every row for this column returns blank?

Comment: No not the entire report, just the column!